# Atomic models of finite automata

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, cellular-automaton

Have their been proposed atomic models of finite automata in the following sense?

Consider as one of the most simple finite automata the [turnstile automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Example:_coin-operated_turnstile) with its state transition table

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
I & S & S' \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Input $I=0$ means "push", $I=1$ means "coin", state $S=0$ means "closed", $S=1$ means "open".

Such an automaton can be realized by an idealized trapped atom with three energy levels $E_0, E_1, E_2$ with $\Delta_0 = E_1 - E_0$, $\Delta_1 = E_2 - E_1$. Let $\Delta_0 \neq \Delta_1$. $\Delta_0$ is identified with input $0$ above, $\Delta_1$ is identified with input $1$.

States $E_0, E_1$ are supposed to be stable and are identified with the two states $0$ and $1$ above, state $E_2$ may decay instantly into state $E_0$ and is not represented in the table.

Sending a photon with energy $\Delta_0$ onto the atom in state $E_0$ puts it into state $E_1$. If it is already in state $E_1$ it may stay there.

Sending a photon with energy $\Delta_1$ onto the atom in state $E_1$ puts it into state $E_2$ which immediately decays into state $E_0$.

This may not be of practical interest, and has probably more to do with finite automata (it is one of many ways to realize them) than with physics. But probably someone has ever given this realization, and I am interested in who and where.

Comment: You can make a state diagram where the transition weights are amplitudes and explore the behavior. The main thing you have to be careful of is that the process *must* be reversible. So if state A goes to state C with amplitude 1, nothing else can go to state C. Basically, you want your arrow weights to be the entries of a unitary matrix.

Comment: [This blog post](http://algorithmicassertions.com/misconception/2015/11/08/Misconceptions-Quantum-Latch.html) has an example of what happens if you break reversibility.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks for the link. This will make things easier (for me to understand).